# How to store the data of two different django models which share one to many relationship via a single HTML form?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I have a single HTML form to fill up the details of both patient and his/her doctor. I have created a One to many relationship between Doctor and Patient models using ForeignKey.

**The form(docpatient.html) goes like this:**

```
<form action="{% url 'requestlanding' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2>
        Patient Details
    </h2>
    <label for="patientName">
        Patient's Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="patientName" name="patientName" required>
    <label for="age">
        Age:
    </label>
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age" required>
    <label for="gender">
        Gender:
    </label>
    <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
        <option value="male">
            Male
        </option>
        <option value="female">
            Female
        </option>
        <option value="other">
            Other
        </option>
    </select>
    <label for="contactNumber">
        Contact Number:
    </label>
    <input type="tel" id="contactNumber" name="contactPatient" required>
    <label for="email">
        Email:
    </label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="emailPatient" required>
    <label for="media">
        Upload patient's picture:
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="media" name="wrecommend" accept="image/*,video/*,pdf/*">
    <h2>
        Doctor Details
    </h2>
    <label for="doctorName">
        Doctor's Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="doctorName" name="doctorName" required>
    <label for="specialization">
        Specialization:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="specialization" id="specialization" required>
    <label for="contactNumber">
        Contact Number:
    </label>
    <input type="tel" id="contactNumber" name="contactDoctor" required>
    <p>
        (All the information must be correct and proper)
    </p>
    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

**I have created Patient and Doctor models as following:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1000000000), MaxValueValidator(9999999999)],
        blank=False,
    )
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Patient(models.Model):
    GENDER = (("Male", "Male"), ("Female", "Female"), ("Others", "Others"))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False, default=None)
    phone = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1000000000), MaxValueValidator(9999999999)],
        blank=False,
        default=None,
    )
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=True, default=0)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=False, default=None)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    wrecommend = models.FileField(
        upload_to="wrecommend", max_length=50, blank=False, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Here is the view that I have created**:

```
def requestlanding(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        p_name = request.POST.get("patientName")
        p_age = request.POST.get("age")
        p_gender = request.POST.get("gender")
        p_phone = request.POST.get("contactPatient")
        p_email = request.POST.get("emailPatient")
        p_wrecommend = request.POST.get("wrecommend")

        d_name = request.POST.get("doctorName")
        d_phone = request.POST.get("contactDoctor")
        d_specialization = request.POST.get("specialization")

        doctor = Doctor.objects.create(
            name=d_name, phone=d_phone, specialization=d_specialization
        )

        doctor.save()

        patient = Patient.objects.create(
            doctor=doctor,
            name=p_name,
            email=p_email,
            phone=p_phone,
            age=p_age,
            gender=p_gender,
            wrecommend=p_wrecommend,
        )

        patient.save()

        return redirect("requestlanding")
    return render(request, "docpatient.html")
```

**I thought this satisfies the doctor-patient relation i.e. one to many relation but while adding two patients with the same doctor, the doctor's details in the database table is being duplicated. But the patients' name in the doctor's record should have been added.

I want the name of the patients of the doctor on the doctor's record.**

**Please help me with this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, your code creates a doctor and patient every time the view is processed successfully, what you need to do is to check if the doctor exists before creating the object and this can be done by Django [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
doctor = Doctor.objects.get_or_create(name=d_name, phone=d_phone, specialization=d_specialization)
#doctor.save()
```

Comment: Please tell me how I can check if the doctor exists or not. I am new to django and could not find any idea.

Comment: The answer shows what to do, get_or_create will either get the doctor from the database or create it and then return it

Comment: Could you please help me with its implementation, I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: put the doctor line as shown in the answer and comment out the doctor.save() call

Comment: Thankyou Elkalioby sir. I have one additional question. why is my file "wrecommend" not being saved in the database?

Comment: Great, please accept the answer and upvote it to close the question. For your question, FileField doesn't save a file to database, it is saved a reference to the file which is stored in MEDIA check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/files/